Why is a functor $\mathcal{V}_{0}(I,-): \mathcal{V}_{0} \to \textbf{Set}$ is the "underlying-set" functor?
I'm reading Kelly's 'Basic Concepts Of Enriched Category Theory' and there is a bit in the introductory section about monoidal categories that confuses me

A monoidal category $\mathcal{V} = (\mathcal{V}_0,\otimes, I, a, l, r)$ consists of a category $\mathcal{V}_0$, a functor $\otimes: \mathcal{V}_0 \times
\mathcal{V}_0 \to \mathcal{V}_{0}$ ...
We then have the representable functor $\mathcal{V}_0(I,−) : \mathcal{V}_0 \to \textbf{Set}$, which we
denote by V. In such cases as Set, Ord, Top, Ab, R-Mod, CGTop∗, it is (to within
isomorphism) the ordinary “underlying-set” functor.

In case of $\mathcal{V}_{0} = \textbf{Ab}$ I interpret the above statement as $\mathcal{V_{0}}(I,-) \simeq U(-)$ where $U(-) :\textbf{Ab} \to \textbf{Set}$ is an underlying set functor for Ab. This however seems to be wrong as $I$ in Ab is a trivial group and the set $\mathcal{V}_{0}(I,G)$ has a single morphism for any group G so $\mathcal{V}_{0}(I,G)$ is not isomorphic to $U(G)$. As far as I know the representable for $U(-)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ so that $\mathcal{V}_{0}(\mathbb{Z},G) \simeq U(G)$ and clearly $I \not \simeq \mathbb{Z}$. Am I misunderstanding something?

"$I$ in $\mathbf{Ab}$ is a trivial group" are you sure? Usually $\mathbf{Ab}$ is considered as a monoidal category under the tensor product of abelian groups, in which case $I = \mathbb{Z}$.

The monoidal structure on $\mathbf{Ab}$ being (implicitly) considered here is the tensor product of abelian groups, whose unit is indeed $\mathbb{Z}$ as you expected.
